# I am trying to compile WRF, while checking System Environment Tests am getting error as shown below

Tags: gcc, compiler, fortran

I have Created a new, clean directory called Build_WRF, and another one called TESTS (placed Fortran and C Tests Tar File inside TESTS). SUCESSFULLY completed 3 TEST. In the 4th TEST -- Fortran Calling a C Function (our gcc and gfortran have different defaults, so we force both to always use 64 bit [-m64] when combining them), 
When i type command

`gcc -c -m64 TEST_4_fortran+c_c.c`

am getting error message like

```
In file included from /usr/include/stdio.h:28:0,
                 from TEST_4_fortran+c_c.c:12:
/usr/include/features.h:324:26: fatal error: bits/predefs.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

Please help me.I tried many things but still its not happening. I am new to LINUX.

Comment: is the `gcc-multilib` package installed?

Answer (score 0):

you would have installed 32 bit linux os on your system. So, you have to write -m32 instead of -m64.
Initially, i had the same problem u have posted. Now, it is working.